# Does Backward scrubbing works as smooth as Forward scrubbing in iOS using AVPlayerItem?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have used AVPlayer for video play. I am using following line of code for Forward scrubbing and it works fine. but when i scrub it backward using slider it seems choppy and skips few frames.

```
let valueToUpdate = Float(value) * Float(self.highlightsPlayer.clipTimeDuration)
self.highlightsPlayer.highlightsPlayerItem?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TimeInterval(valueToUpdate), 240))
```

Is there any solution that forward and backward scrubbing works in same way?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with compression and key-frames. Imagine you're scanning through a video that's been compressed. Every 10 seconds you get a full image but for every frame between those 10 second frames you just get the pixels that have changed. So scanning forward is easy, you just combine pixels as you go and show fewer frames depending on speed. Going backwards is not so easy. To go even 1 frame behind one of your key frames you need to jump back to the previous keyframe (10 seconds back) and then make up all the images until the one you needed.

Obviously this is a bit simplified as there are variable rate compression algorithms but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: great info. How can I re-encode it to make it scrub fast for backward as well?